# Convergence of series $ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \sin\left( \frac{n\pi}{6}\right)$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Decide if the series $ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \sin\left( \frac{n\pi}{6}\right)$ converges or not.

I've tried to use the ratio test but I had no success. I don't see how other convergence tests could work.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Can you think of any two subsequences of $\{\sin(n\frac {\pi}6)\}_n$ that converge to disparate values?

Comment: @abiessu yes, but I don't get why is this important since I am talking about the serie

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Hint:** What is $\lim_{n\to\infty}\sin\left(\frac{n\pi}{6}\right)$?

Comment: It does not exists, but I don't see how this can help

Comment: @user2768645: If it doesn't exist, then it must not equal $0$...

Comment: Ok, is this a criterion of convergence?

Comment: It is the first [test for convergence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convergence_tests) taught in most calculus courses.

Comment: I didn't know it. Thanks for your attention!